# Android Bluetooth: file transfer over BluetoothSocket

Tags: android, bluetooth

I wish to perform device-to-device file transfer over Bluetooth in my Android application.  Currently I have written the code necessary to make connections between multiple Bluetooth devices and I have retrieved connected BluetoothSockets for data exchange.

Is there a library available which implements file transfer that can be given a socket, or streams to use?

If not, can someone point me towards information about implementing the ability myself?

I am very new to file transfer programming and Bluetooth, so any help is appreciated.

Also, because I want this functionality built into my app, I am not looking to just run some other end-user app on the phone, I really do need to be able to code against this functionality (whether via a library, or my own implementation).

Comment: Hi Matt, I am facing a very similar issue, please how did you solve yours? Thanks! LISA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally over Bluetooth you would use something like [OPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Object_Push_Profile_.28OPP.29).

However that doesn't [seem](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html) to be implemented on Android yet...

What I would do, is try serializing the data and sending it via RFCOMM or SPP bit by bit. For XML there is [XStream](http://jars.de/java/android-xml-serialization-with-xstream), or, even simpler, Google's [Protobuf](http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/overview.html).

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Its very interesting that you mention this.  Since I posted this, I have implemented my own protocol for sending and receiving various data including files.  I did not come across XStream, but I did find Google's Protocol Buffers.  I was very close to using Protocol Buffers until I decided that for my limited needs it would probably be faster and easier to implement my own simple FTP-like protocol.  However, I may move to Protocol Buffers if my app gets popular.